# RISCV Inline Assembly in GCC: Atomic Load/Store

Tags: assembly, gcc, inline-assembly, riscv, bare-metal

Edit:

I believe that the clue here was "Illegal *operand". The problem was with operands. I changed some operand ATTRIBUTES from "m" (or whatever) to "A", and I made progress. For RISC-V, if you are passing an address/pointer, you must use "A" attribute!

---

Colleagues!

Please consider this block of inline gcc assembly (excerpted from `foo.c`):

```
  asm volatile(
    "als_%=:\n\t"
    "  lr.w.aq  t1, %[src]\n\t"
    "  sc.w.rl  t0, t1, %[dst]\n\t"
    "  bnez     t0, als_%="
    : [dst] "=&m" (*((uint32_t*)(0x27402448ULL)))
    : [src] "m"   (*((uint32_t*)(0x000a0018ULL))));
```

- It intends to, first, load the contents of the source address to t1.
- Then to, second, store the contents of t1 to the destination address.
- Finally, if the store fails (looking at status in t0), then the process will be attempted again.

Note that there is no "symbol" at these addresses.  We're running bare-metal code, creating pathological coherency scenarios among "interesting" random memory locations.

I get this error using SiFive's pre-built gcc-8.3.0:

```
foo.c: Assembler messages:
foo.c:1106: Error: illegal operands `lr.w t1,8(a4)`
foo.c:1107: Error: illegal operands `sc.w t0,t1,1048(s0)`
```

I've tried to `la` from those locations into temporary registers and then to use the registers in the ld/st instructions, but I get similar errors on the `la`.

My command line is:

```
/path/to/riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc-8.3.0-2019.08.0-x86_64-linux-centos6/bin/riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc \
-ggdb3 \
-std=gnu99 \
-Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wshadow -Wstack-usage=1024 -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-unused-parameter \
-ffunction-sections \
-fdata-sections \
-I/path/to/target/include \
--specs=nano.specs \
-Os \
-nostartfiles \
-nostdlib \
-Xlinker -Map=foo.map \
-march=rv64imafdc \
-mabi=lp64d \
-mcmodel=medany \
-malign-data=natural \
-mriscv-attribute \
-I/path/to/freedom-e-sdk/bsp/qemu-sifive-u54mc/install/include \
-L/path/to/freedom-e-sdk/bsp/qemu-sifive-u54mc/install/lib/debug \
foo.c \
-T../riscv64/link.ld \
-Wl,--start-group \
  -lc -lgcc -lm -lmetal -lmetal-gloss \
-Wl,--end-group \
-Wl,--gc-sections \
-o foo.elf;
```

Comment: Have you tried manually assembling those instructions into machine code, then using `objdump -d` to see what syntax it wants you to use?  Or maybe it's a matter of telling the assembler about CPU features if those instructions aren't baseline.  (Sorry I don't know RISC-V well enough to know if they are or not.)  Perhaps try using `stdatomic.h`'s `atomic_fetch_add_explicit()` with `memory_order_acq_rel` and see the syntax of LL/SC instructions GCC itself emits for its `__atomic` builtins?

Comment: @PeterCordes, Thanks for your help! I can't use <stdatomic.h> even for testing because no one has ever implemented the methods that underlie them for RISCV32/RISCV64, like __atomic_load_16().  Anything in bare-metal will fail with link errors that use those (even using gcc-11.2.0, which I've also tried).

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Pe6e4j7bf shows `atomic_fetch_add_explicit` on an `_Atomic int*` inlines just fine with rv64 GCC 10.2.0, to `fence iorw,ow;` and `amoadd.w.aq zero,a5,0(a0)` instructions.  I'm not surprised `__atomic_load_16` couldn't inline, 16-byte atomics may not be lock-free even on RV64 and thus need library support.

Comment: Or more relevantly, for an atomic_load (mo_acquire), with that set of ISA extensions, GCC uses plain `lw` + barrier, not an `lr.w.aq`.  https://godbolt.org/z/6n8q3PjTh.  Your GAS does apparently recognize them, though, otherwise I think it would complain about the mnemonic, not the operands.

Comment: @old_timer: I don't think removing `[assembly]` was appropriate here.  Clearly there's a problem with actually assembling those asm instructions, not with the GNU C inline asm syntax and constraints that got the compiler to emit that string and feed it to GAS.  Some [inline-assembly] questions aren't really [assembly] questions, but that's not the case here.  It would be the same question if using those instructions is a `.S` file.

Comment: fair enough I didnt see that the OP had tried real assembly nor had tried godbolt or other sources of different versions of gas.

Comment: @old_timer: The question doesn't mention having actually tried a separate `.S` file, but we know that GCC works by creating a `.s` and feeding it to GAS.  So those assembler error messages are coming from the real assembler that would be used if you did try that in stand-alone asm.  So unlike clang or MSVC, there's no argument that the compiler's built-in assembler might be different from real assembly language; GCC doesn't have a built-in assembler.

Comment: Okay, I *think* the clue here was "illegal **operand*".  The problem was with operands.  I changed operand ATTRIBUTES from "m" (or whatever) to "A", and I made progress.  For RISC-V, if you are passing an address/pointer, you must use "A" attribute.